# How to start headless X upon boot for non-root users in Debian

Tags: debian, xserver, xvfb

My requirement is a little different from [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/251961/getting-xvfb-to-start-upon-booting-system-in-ubuntu-maverick) in that I would like to launch a window manager for each of two non-root users upon boot.

For testing, first I prepare the following lines in *.xinitrc* and/or *.xsession* in home directories of *user2* and *user3* like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec icewm
```

Then I manually login to virtual console as *user2* or *user3* or open an xterm window and type this command:

```
xinit -- /usr/bin/Xvfb :3 -cc 4 -screen 0 1024x768x16
```

This does the job - icewm and Xvfb run behind the scene.

Now I want to automate the login and command *xinit* on boot. However none of the following approaches work:

Either manually type these two commands as root or place them in /etc/rc.local:

```
su -l user2 -c xinit -- /usr/bin/Xvfb :3 -cc 4 -screen 0 1024x768x16

No protocol specified
IceWM: Can't open display: :0. X must be running and $DISPLAY set.

start-stop-daemon --start -u user2 -g user2 -b --pidfile /tmp/pid --exec /usr/bin/xinit -- -- Xvfb :3
ps ax

[Xorg] <defunct>
```

Helps will be greatly appreciated!

**[Edit after testing alex.d.'s approach]**

File */home/user2/.xsession*:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=localhost:3
export XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority
exec icewm
```

Issue this command as root:

```
su -l user2 -c /usr/bin/startx -- /usr/bin/Xvfb :3 &
```

I get this:

```
hostname: Name or service not known
xauth: (stdin):1:  bad display name "example.com:2" in "add" command

IceWM: Can't open display: localhost:3. X must be running and $DISPLAY set.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
xauth: (argv):1:  bad display name "example.com:2" in "remove" command
```

Any idea? Please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my working approach.

file */etc/systemd/system/john.service:*

```
[Unit]
Description=xinit - user "john"

[Service]
User=john
Group=john
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xinit openbox-session -- /usr/bin/Xvfb :1 -nolisten tcp
ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/killall -u john

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

file */home/john/.config/openbox/autostart*:

```
wine my_program.exe
```

Thank you all for the helps!

Answer (score 0):

When starting X11 from rc.local, it's not started from inside a user session (consolekit or logind), so things are missing in the environment.
Instead of a bare xinit, you should try to start X11 with startx which is intended to start a session.

Comment: I have just used *startx* instead and edited to show issues coming with that script.

Comment: Why do you explicitely force values for $DISPLAY and $XAUTHORITY?
In particular, DISPLAY=localhost:3 will work only if X is listenning on TCP sockets. It should be DISPLAY=:3 (or better: do not set it, startx will do it for you).
And why force a value for XAUTHORITY? Especially if you do it in the .Xsession, it's to late and you lose the value set by startx.